# Show a Column Sorted by default in a DataGrid WPF XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I'm trying to have a column sorted by default in a DataGrid in XAML.
I've tried several approaches but none of them work.
The last one I've tried it's this, it works the first time I run the program but then it's overruled somehow.

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Bar"
    Width="50"
    CanUserSort="True"
    HeaderStyle="{StaticResource CenterGridHeaderStyle}"
    Binding="{BindingBarName,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
    SortDirection="Ascending">
    <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
         <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
              <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Center" />
         </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: Overruled by what and how? How do you set the `ItemsSource`?

Comment: The source comes automatically from the binding, and its in double format. it works for the normal sort when i click the column header.

Comment: So what doesn't work? Please clarify your question, the expected results and describe the current behaviour.

Comment: I wanted to have a column sorted when the progra runs. Like a default sorting.

Comment: Then you should sort the source collection?

Comment: I could but it would be a more time expensive solution than do it in XAML, in my program i use data treatment from REVIT, it already takes a lot of time running.

Comment: Hmm...you are not sorting anything in the XAML currently. You just display a visual indicator. You need to sort the source collection or the view of it one way or another.

Comment: yes i am, because in each column is "CanUserSort="True"", so it can be sorted manually

Comment: To sort the items in the view, you should add a `SortDescription` to the `DataGrid`. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `DataGridColumn.SortDirection` doesn't actually sort the column. It's just used to display the arrow indicator in the header.

To actually sort the items, you should also add a `SortDescription` to the `DataGrid`:

```
dataGrid1.Items.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("BarName", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
```